# What is a good alternative to Remastersys/UB/UCK?

Tags: remastersys, uck

I'm eager to use my respin of Ubuntu 14.04 on my other machines. The problem is that since Remastersys and Ubuntu Builder are discontinued, it's hard to find a good alternative. For some reason UCK won't work on my computer (even with various tweaks people post to make it work). It doesn't have to be a GUI program, but at least a bit usable. I also want to customize Ubiquity and install it with a USB. The system will be used within my company.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also note that [Rinzwind's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/49679/158442) while more manual, works well across all current versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Relinux looks very promising. But how do I change Ubiquity so it will install with the customized version? Will it take the changes I make from the root file of the current system?

Comment: @muru a lot of people will advice UCK if not specifically told that it won't work and also UB is no longer "usable". Believe me if I say I searched a lot of sites for good alternatives to make a customized installer and installation.

Comment: My recommendation is Rinzwind's answer. I'm tired of making the frontends like RemasterSys play nice.

Comment: @muru <3 I would like to state that the manual method will teach you things and it is not that hard.

Comment: I ended up using Systemback, which makes a complete backup of your system. The backup can be used to make an ISO and Live CD.